# Change the size of the ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, style

I want to put two ListDensityPlot together using "Style" command, but I don't how to control the size of the plot to make it the same height of the legend. The following the is code

```
p = ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.05}, {j, 0, 3, 0.05}], ColorFunction ->"SolarColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Style[Grid[{{"Title", SpanFromLeft}, {p, p}}, Spacings -> 0, ItemStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "CMU Serif", FontSize -> 40]], LineBreakWithin -> False]
```

The figure I want is

[image]

After I run the code kglr mention and set "LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 500}"

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.05}, {j, 0, 3, 0.05}], ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", ImageSize -> {200, 200}, PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 500}]]
```

But it doesn't change the legend size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `ImageSize` in `ListDensityPlot` and the option `LegendMarkerSize` in `BarLegend` with the same value for vertical size:

```
ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.05}, {j, 0, 3, 0.05}],
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 200}]]
```

[image]

Use `ImageSize -> {360, 360}` and `LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 360}` to get

[image]

Using `ImageSize -> Automatic` and `LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 360}` gives the same picture.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I run the code you mention and set "LegendMarkerSize -> {Automatic, 500}", but it doesn't work, my Mathematica's version is 12.0.0.0. I have edit my question and show the picture there.

Comment: @JieJiang, in version 12.2.0, use `LegendMarkerSize -> {15,500}` .

Comment: OK I see. Thank you again!